# Handling java stopwatch start and stop errors

Tags: java, stopwatch

as you know if you try .start() an already started stopwatch in the org.apache.commons.lang3 class it crashes saying that it has already started. The same goes for stopping it.
Is there any neater way (Other than try catch) to handle this. Kind of like in c# where it just ignores the statement if the stopwatch has already started.
I'm also having this problem with the sound effects on the LibGDX framework.
Any Ideas?
Thanks alot!

Comment: Can you post some example code? The stacktrace? And what do you mean "as you know?"

Comment: StopWatch may not be the best class for this purpose, after all what is the use of a stopwatch if you don't know if/when it was started? There may be another class such as `Timer` better suited to your needs.

Comment: Does something help you in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [the docs of `getTime()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html#getTime%28%29) .

The method should return `0`, if the watch isn't started. Explore [the source code](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html#line.263) to verify that:

```
public long getTime() {
    if (this.runningState == STATE_STOPPED || this.runningState == STATE_SUSPENDED) {
        return this.stopTime - this.startTime;
    } else if (this.runningState == STATE_UNSTARTED) {
        return 0;
    } else if (this.runningState == STATE_RUNNING) {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - this.startTime;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Illegal running state has occured. ");
}
```

So you can use this, instead of try-catch:

```
if(watch.getTime() == 0L) {
    watch.start();
}
```

and

```
if(watch.getTime() > 0L) {
    watch.stop();
}
```

Hope it helps.